# What we need to put in wp_config.php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I tried uploading a wordpress site and I arrived to the step when I need to modify wp-config.php
Here's the code.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'replace_with_database_name_you_noted_down');

/** MySQL database username */

define('DB_USER', 'replace_with_new_host_mysql_user_name');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'replace_with_new_host_mysql_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'replace_with_new_mysql_host'
```

I don't understand what means "replace with new mysql host", because I have the files in wordpress directory and when I try to access the page, it returns "403 forbidden.The access for the server was 
denied".

I mention that i tried that on a simple installation wordpress site, I cannot upload my site on cpanel, can you send me a tutorial and give me some suggestions please ?

Comment: Wordpress has extensive documentation. I suggest you start by reading that, and then try our sister site https://wordpress.stackexchange.com if there's something you can't find there (be sure to read their FAQ first to understand what they will consider a "good question").

Comment: dont forget that wordpress has, once you fire it up the first time (index.php) has a nice step by step instal. Follow that, and make sure you create your database with user via your cpanel

Answer (score 0):

In order to work wordpress need a sql database. You need to create one and a user with a password.

If you have cpanel you can install directly wordpress with one click with softaculous or other. This will create a database automaticaly and fill the wp-config for you.

If you install wordpress "manually", you have to fill the wp-config yourself. For MySQL hostname, you can try localhost (if the sql database and ftp hosting is at the same place)

Comment: Thank you so much for help, but I solved the problem in another way. I have just modified my "htaccess".